# What could be the cause of error in my code?

Tags: php, mysql

I get a notice of trying to find a property of non object each time I try to run the following query:

```
public function doesEmailExist($dbvars){
            $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE email = ':email' AND hash = ':hash'");
            $this->db->bind(':email', $dbvars['email']);
            $this->db->bind(':hash', $dbvars['hash']);
            // assign row 
            $row = $this->db->single();
            return $row;
        }
Below is the database method that is responsible for fetching the data:
public function single(){
        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
 } 

     //check if email exist
        if($job->doesEmailExist($dbvars)->num_rows > 0) {
         // redirect and send a message
         header("location:error.php");
        }else{
          // Register user as an unverified
          if($job->create($dbvars)){
            echo "submitted";
          }
        }
```

IMPORTANT: $job is an instance of the class that owns the method"doesEmailExist()" .

Here is the error message
Notice: Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\mylifepro\tero_biz\apply.php on line 48

The function doesEmailExist() is display "bool(false)" on var_dump; Why?

Comment: IMPORTANT: use sql parameters instead of plain query. You are opened to SQL injections

Comment: The method `doesEmailExist` returns an the value from `$this->db->single()`, so it depends on what this method returns.

Comment: `$this->db->bind(':email', $dbvars['email']);` - but I don't see `:email` placeholder in the query text.

Comment: You're binding on a query where you directly injected the parameter values. You're mixing two syntaxes. Replace the injected values with placeholders.

Comment: Thanks to you all. i replaced the injected parameters with placeholders also i remove the single quotes around the placeholders and the function returns object as expected.